# ¿como ordeno de mayor a menor de un vector a otro sin usar en sort?

Tags: javascript

hola tengo un problema y es que me han pedido que intente pasar de un vector con números desordenados a otro ordenados llevo varios días dándole vueltas y no consigo nada. aquí os dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
var Key
var Lista = []
var Lista2 = []
var exit = true

do{
    Key = prompt("Introduzca numeros aleatoriamente:")
    if (Key === "#" ){
        exit=false
    }else{
        Lista.push(Number(Key))
    }
}while(exit)

for (var i = 0; i < Lista.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < Lista2.length; j++) {
        if(Lista2.length==0){
            Lista2.push(Lista[i])
        }else if(Lista2[j]>Lista[i]){
            var aux = Lista2[j]
            Lista2[j-1] = Lista[i]
            Lista2[j]=aux
        }
    }      
}
console.log(Lista);
```

Comment: puedes ordenarlo con los algoritmos mas comunes de ordenamiento `burbuja` `merge` , etc te dejo uno [Ordenamiento burbuja en Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817334/javascript-bubble-sort)

Comment: Y cual es el problema de ese codigo?

Comment: Hay muchos algoritmos para ordenar [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-algorithms/) están explicados muchos o la mayoría.